# How can poor people afford many children with lack of birth control?

Tags: children, birth-control

Many prominent Islamic scholars [discourage popular birth control methods](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/21169). But how can poor people afford to raise so many children?  Also some women consider this as their violation of their rights, and would not like to become a children-producing factory. So how can poor people afford many children with lack of such birth control methods?

Comment: this might help: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/is-it-obligatory-in-islam-to-continue-to-have-more-children-when-you-cant-provi

Answer (score 4):

Allah has symbolised the relation between a man and wife with a farmer and his farm. A farmer take care of his land, makes sure it is healthy. He does not deprive the land of essential nutrients by sowing the same crop again and again. He may even skip a season to revive the land. Thus he use every possible mean to make sure that the land is fit for its purpose.

Similarly a man can use any means necessary to make sure that his wife's health is not compromised, including birth control.

The other point is that, there are some things that are in direct control of Allah, eg sun and moon. There are other things which happens through some "asbab" that involve humans, eg child birth. Human beings are required to use their intellect and best judgement in these matters.

What would you say about a farmer who just throws seeds in a farm and expects a good crop.

Comment: +1: excellent parable, I was thinking on answering on similar lines , a farmer expects a rich harvest!

Comment: Nice answer, please provide any reference for better understanding of mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not put any reference for this but still I like to add to clear your mind from 2 sides,

1- Do not kill your children because of hunger.

2- PBUH said that on judgement day I will be proud of my maximum Ummah. (mean as many we are as much PBUH will be happy how we can be more than they only way in my sense is making children.)

if we are still on thinking the same thing which said birth control than we are still in the same age where people kill there daughters.

If my answer clear your mind that will be my honor and if not you can ask the points.