# Is it halal to use condom even if you can provide for the kid and don’t have any medical issue

Tags: children

I often hear people ask this question and the answer Can you use condom  if you can’t provide for the kid? And it’s yes but imagine the couple can provide for the kid but don’t want one yet so they use condom just for pleasure and the women or the men don’t have any medical problems. is it still halal in this case even tho they have money to provide for the kid ?

Comment: Does this answer cover your question?  [Link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/4198/25645)