# Is it haram to adopt instead of giving birth?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, children, child-adoption

I'm a young muslim woman who wants to have children in the futur when i'll get married, but i always wanted to adopt and not give birth to my own children. I was wondering if it was prohibited to do so, knowing that i'm healthy with no fertility issus? I prefer to avoid giving birth for several reasons, and i really want to help an orphan to get a better life, so i would like to know if it's permissible to only adopt and not have my own kids with the use of temporary birth control such as the pill, with the consent of my partner of course.

Answer (score 1):

Contraception is considered permissible when it is done with the consent of both partners - it is however discouraged (see [Is it permissible to use contraception during intercourse?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38380/)).

Taking care of orphans is recommended act, as evident by the hadith already cited in the other answer.

Note however that the orphans will not become your legal children, so there are some concerns you should be aware of, for example:

- They will retain their biological father's name.
- The males will be non-mahrams to you and the females will be non-mahrams to your husband. This effects several rulings. To overcome this and make them mahrams, you would need suckle them while they are less than 2 years old. This would be complicated if you don't have children of your own, so you would have to have the male children suckled by your sisters and the female children would have to be suckled by the husband's sisters.
- They will not inherit from you, rather your estate would go to the next of kin such as your siblings etc.; while you can only make a bequest of a maximum of 1/3rd for them.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting an orphan or abandonned child is mustahab (good/welcome/beneficial).

[Bukhari 78:36](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6005)

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I and the person who looks after an orphan and
> provides for him, will be in Paradise like this," putting his index
> and middle fingers together.

Voluntarily not giving birth in absence of fertility problems was not a real option in the time of the Prophet ﷺ as means of birth control did not exist. The method of control in pre-Islam Arabia seems to have been killing children which is strictly prohibited in Quran and Hadith. The application of modern birth control means is disputed in Islam (because any fiqh is extrapolated), considered haram according to Shia fiqh, else halal (but rather to the makruh side). A discussion of this topic see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/is-it-obligatory-in-islam-to-continue-to-have-more-children-when-you-cant-provi).

Altogether, your idea is rather not supported by Islam.

Apart from formal fiqh, please consider that in present, new-born children are not so frequently orphan or abandonned; couples who involuntarily have no children who are wishing to adopt a baby are more frequent. If you want to do something beneficial, you would rather adopt a child at higher age.

---

Please read the answer from UmH. Concerning the status of an adopted child, if you are living in a non-muslim country, you may face an incoherent status of an adoptive child: according to Islamic fiqh it is as described by UmH; the official status in my country is however equal to a native child in all aspects (name, inheritance, marriage between adoptive siblings).